# Use of uninitialized value in string eq at ./parse_rss.pl line 27

Tags: arrays, linux, perl, ubuntu

**Background:**

Im not a PERL expert but working on migrating some scripts to a new server with newer versions of Perl and PHP all the others work but this particular one doesnt work.

I have installed all of the modules this script depends on to run, and those PM related errors have ceased.

**Environment:**

- Web Server Running
- Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 64-bit
- Apache 2
- Mysql
- PHP5
- FREETDS
- ALL Firewall permission and remote Database Connectivity
  tested and verified
- ALL required Perl Modules and Apache/PHP5
  extensions tested and verified

**Script functionality:**

The script is meant to pull stories from an RSS feed and place them into a remote database.

**Problem:**

On the old server the script runs with no problems on this new server i get the following error:

> Use of uninitialized value in string eq at ./parse_rss.pl line 27.

**Line 27 is the following:**

```
if (ref($item->{'company:symbol'} eq 'ARRAY')) {
                next;
```

**Please view the full Script below:**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
#

use warnings;
use strict;
use DateTime;
use DateTime::Format::ISO8601;
use XML::FeedPP;

my $starttime;
if ($#ARGV == -1) {
        $starttime = DateTime::Format::ISO8601->parse_datetime("1970-01-01T00:00:00");
}
else {
        $starttime = DateTime::Format::ISO8601->parse_datetime($ARGV[0]);
}

my $feed = XML::FeedPP->new("http://RSS.FEED.URL");
my $num_items = $feed->get_item();
for (my $i = $num_items - 1; $i >= 0; $i--)
{
        my $item = $feed->get_item($i);
        my $dt = DateTime::Format::ISO8601->parse_datetime($item->pubDate);
        if ($dt < $starttime) {
                last;
        }
        if (ref($item->{'company:symbol'} eq 'ARRAY')) {
                next;
        }
        if ($item->title =~ /(.+?) (upgraded|downgraded) to (.+?) from (.+?) at (.+)/) {
                print sprintf("%04d-%02d-%02d %02d:%02d:%02d", $dt->year(), $dt->month(), $dt->day(), $dt->hour(), $dt->minute(), $dt->second()) . "|$1|" . $item->{'company:symbol'} . "|$2|$3|$4|$5\n";
        }
        elsif ($item->title =~ /(.+?) (initiated) with (\w+) (.+?) at (.+)/) {
                print sprintf("%04d-%02d-%02d %02d:%02d:%02d", $dt->year(), $dt->month(), $dt->day(), $dt->hour(), $dt->minute(), $dt->second()) . "|$1|" . $item->{'company:symbol'} . "|$2|$4|...None...|$5\n";
        }
}
```

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated

Comment: What is the value of `$item`? You can easily print a hash with [`Data::Dumper`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Dumper)

Comment: Those parentheses are surely wrong. `ref($foo eq "bar")` will always return an empty string because the result of `eq` is never a reference.

Answer (score 0):

Your parentheses are in the wrong place

```
if (ref($item->{'company:symbol'} eq 'ARRAY')) {
```

Should be

```
if (ref($item->{'company:symbol'}) eq 'ARRAY') {
```

`ref` returns a string, which in the case of an array happens to be `ARRAY`. Hence this checks whether the reference in that hash element is an array reference.

Answer (score 0):

As [***TLP*** says](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36139308/622310), the problem is with your line

```
if (ref($item->{'company:symbol'} eq 'ARRAY'))
```

The expression `$item->{'company:symbol'} eq 'ARRAY'` evaluates to either *true* or *false*—1 or the empty string—and the `ref` operator returns false—the empty string—in both cases because neither is a reference

You meant to check whether the hash element was an array reference, so

```
if (ref $item->{'company:symbol'} eq 'ARRAY')
```

with no parentheses at all would would fine

There's a number of other issues with your code. In particular I think it's neater to extract the functions of an iterated value at the start of the loop.

So, for instance

```
if (ref($item->{'company:symbol'} eq 'ARRAY')) {
    next;
}
```

is clearer written as

```
my $company_symbol = $item->{'company:symbol'};

next if ref $company_symbol eq 'ARRAY';
```

Here's a version of your code that you may prefer

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

use DateTime;
use DateTime::Format::ISO8601;
use XML::FeedPP;

my $starttime;

if ( @ARGV ) {
    $starttime = DateTime::Format::ISO8601->parse_datetime( $ARGV[0] );
}
else {
    $starttime = DateTime::Format::ISO8601->parse_datetime('1970-01-01T00:00:00');
}

my $feed      = XML::FeedPP->new('http://rss.feed.url');
my $num_items = $feed->get_item;

for ( my $i = $num_items - 1; $i >= 0; --$i ) {

    my $item           = $feed->get_item($i);
    my $company_symbol = $item->{'company:symbol'};
    my $pub_date       = DateTime::Format::ISO8601->parse_datetime( $item->pubDate );
    my $title          = $item->title;

    last if $pub_date < $starttime;

    next if ref $company_symbol eq 'ARRAY';

    if ( $title =~ /(.+?) (upgraded|downgraded) to (.+?) from (.+?) at (.+)/ ) {

        print join('|',
            $pub_date->strftime('%Y-%m-%d %h:%m:%s'),
            $1,
            $company_symbol,
            $2,
            $3,
            $4,
            $5
        ), "\n";
    }
    elsif ( $title =~ /(.+?) (initiated) with (\w+) (.+?) at (.+)/ ) {

        print join('|',
            $pub_date->strftime('%Y-%m-%d %h:%m:%s'),
            $1,
            $company_symbol,
            $2,
            $4,
            '...None...',
            $5
        ), "\n";
    }
}
```